# mongodb aggregate two array request

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, aggregate

I run a webserver connecting to mongodb. The user will send a request in a JSON which mainly consist of two arrays ID and DATE. I need to check all the possibility of both array

This is sample request array:
Time : ["2019-03-07T19:50:07.000Z","2019-03-07T20:50:07.000Z"]
ID : ["EX70","EX60"]

I need to find result for each match : EX70 during or before 2019-03-07T19:50:07.000Z; EX70 during or before 2019-03-07T20:50:07.000Z; EX60 during or before 2019-03-07T19:50:07.000Z; EX60 during or before 2019-03-07T20:50:07.000Z.

`nodejs`

```
 collection_actual_excavator.aggregate([
{"$match":{"$and":[{Excavator_ID: {$in: reqExcavatorarray}},{"TIME" 
                 {"$lte": new Date (reqDatearray)}}]}}, 
{$sort: { TIME: -1 }},
{$group: {_id: "$Excavator_ID",_res:{$push:"$$CURRENT"}}},
{$project: {_res:{ $slice: ["$_res",0,1] }}}
])
```

Code not working array ID and array DATE

`nodejs`

```
 collection_actual_excavator.aggregate([
{"$match":{"$and":[{Excavator_ID: {$in: reqExcavatorarray}},{"TIME" 
                 {"$lte": new Date (singledate)}}]}}, 
{$sort: { TIME: -1 }},
{$group: {_id: "$Excavator_ID",_res:{$push:"$$CURRENT"}}},
{$project: {_res:{ $slice: ["$_res",0,1] }}}
])
```

working code for array ID single-DATE

I need to find result for each match : EX70 during or before 2019-03-07T19:50:07.000Z; EX70 during or before 2019-03-07T20:50:07.000Z; EX60 during or before 2019-03-07T19:50:07.000Z; EX60 during or before 2019-03-07T20:50:07.000Z.